# Drop Down Alignment

Tags: html, css

I am working on a supposedly simple drop down menu using HTML and CSS, and have encountered an issue. After scouring google and the forums to no avail, figured it was time to ask. I am trying to get the drop down menu to line up with it's parent element.

I have experimented with a few different methods, so far the most hopeful seems to be setting the "left:" value to the necessary percentage.

This brings up another issue though:
Issue: when I set the left value, I end up with a bunch of blank space to the right of the item that I can't seem to get rid of. Can't get the width right.

Code located here: https://jsfiddle.net/c6mz3t08/5/

HTML

```
    <div id="navbar-top">
    <ul class="horizontal">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About
            <ul>                    
                <li>Menu 1</li>
                <li>Menu 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Header</li>
        <li>Header</li>
        <li>Header</li>
    </ul>
```

CSS for dropdown

```
.horizontal li ul {
opacity:0;
visibility:hidden;
text-align:left;
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:-38%;  //end up with blank space on right?
}

.horizontal li ul li {
position:relative;
background-color:#BBB;
display:block;
width:100%;
}
```

It seems the alignment problem happens because the `<ul>` starts after the word "About" in the second `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

a.) for positioning adjust the `left`parameter in `.horizontal li ul` (-39px seems to work well).

b.) for the width of the submenus adjust the `width` parameter in `.horizontal li ul li` (70px worked well here, but depends on the content)

Answer (score 0):

Do not guess on the `left`. The reason it is pushed to the right is because the `ul` has by default some padding.

Setting the padding to 0 and the left to 0 will fix this.

The space on the right is added because you set the width to 100%. If you remove the width it will fit its container. But that might not be what you want because the text will wrap, it might be better to set `white-space:nowrap` on it.

```
.horizontal li ul {
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    text-align:left;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    padding:0;
    left:0;   //using the LEFT parameter to get it in to alignment--end up with "blank" space on right?
}

.horizontal li ul li {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#BBB;
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Updated demo at https://jsfiddle.net/c6mz3t08/6/

Comment: This also worked! I got the alignment just right by setting the padding to
        .horizontal li ul li {
 position:relative;
 background-color:#BBB;
 display:block;
        padding:14px 19px 0 19px; // padding values to match top li item
        white-space:nowrap; //got rid of whitespace
        }